# context.SaveChanges return 0 when updated without any change

Tags: c#, entity-framework

context.SaveChanges() returns 0 if I only hit the update button. If I don't change anything and just hit the update button, it returns 0. I am checking on the value which is returned by SaveChanges. Which are the conditions where SaveChanges returns 0. What are the return values indicate?

Following is my code.

```
int returnValue = CS.SaveChanges();
                   return returnValue == 1 ? "User profile has been updated successfully" : "Unable to update";
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx) the return value is the number of objects updated in the context:

```
Return Value
Type: System.Int32
The number of objects written to the underlying database.
```

So your method could look like this:

```
int returnValue = CS.SaveChanges();
return returnValue > 0 ? 
    String.Format("{0} User profiles have been updated successfully.", returnvalue) : 
    "No updates have been written to the database.";
```